# Should using USE/FORCE INDEX change the EXPLAIN output in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

As title suggests, should the `EXPLAIN` output change after explicitly using `FORCE INDEX (index_1, index_2)` in a query?

As an example I have the following query:

```
select
    person_id,
    role_id,
    scope_id,
    count(distinct qualification_id) as ncomps
from dw_rolepersonqualification
where ((mandatory = 'y') and (expiry_date > now()))
group by 1, 2, 3
```

When I run it with `EXPLAIN`, I get:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: dw_rolepersonqualification
type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY, idx_person, idx_role, idx_qualification, idx_scope, idx_mandatory
key: null
key_len: null
ref: null
rows: 8267852
Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

When I add in `FORCE INDEX (dx_person, idx_role, idx_qualification, idx_scope)` it does not change the output of `EXPLAIN`. Is this to be expected or am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see the definitions of the indexes, plus datatypes, to help you here.

Comment: @RickJames I'm not actually requesting optimisation tips, I just wanted to know if using ```FORCE INDEX``` should change the ```EXPLAIN``` output.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal index for that query is

```
INDEX(mandatory,  -- tested with "=", so first
      expiry_date)  -- a range
```

Even so, it may decide that the index is not worth the effort.  If the Optimizer estimates that more than ~20% of the table matches the `WHERE` clause, it will decide to scan the table rather than bouncing between the index's BTree and the data BTree.

A "covering" index may (or may not) be better:

```
INDEX(mandatory,  -- tested with "=", so first
      expiry_date,  -- a range
      person_id, role_id, scope_id,
            qualification_id) -- all other touched columns (any order)
```

(Caveat:  Some of what I say may not be valid; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

My Mantra:  "Force Index may help today, but hurt tomorrow."